# How can I tell AutoHotKey to ignore the key (space bar) the executes the script?

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following autohotkey script:

```
::aaim::==aim{ENTER}int{ENTER}{ENTER}12{UP}{HOME}
```

which produces this:

```
==aim
int

12
```

however, to execute it I have to type aaim**SPACE** which then puts a space after where I want my cursor to be, like this:

```
==aim
int
 |
12
```

**How can tell autohotkey to not include the SPACE the executes the script?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:*:aaim::`

Replace the first bit with that. It'll now fire when you type aaim, and nothing else. (That might be a little annoying if you're typing something that begins with aaim, but it's smart enough to not do it in the middle of words)

Answer (score 2):

You could also avoid typing most of the spacing manually and use brackets, they will retain spaces:

```
:r0*:aaim::
(
==aim
int

12
{Left}{Up}
)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a function in AutoHotkey specifically for this purpose. "Omit" Note the O in the hotstring below:

```
:O:aaim::==aaim etc... etc...
```

For more information, open the AutoHotkey help file and click on "Hotstrings & auto-replace" in the contents menu. Omit is listed under the Options headline.

Answer (score 1):

::aaim::==aim{ENTER}int{ENTER}{ENTER}12{UP}{HOME}{BACKSPACE}

There.

Comment: A roundabout, slightly hacky, but above all working method! +1, because who cares if our coding is perfect :P